# ExtJS Chart Label Issue

Tags: charts, extjs5

I have a `cartesian` Chart with multiple series. One series is a *Bar* and the other series is a *Line*. The line axis label is not rendering the correct values corresponding to the data entered for the line.

For instance my store data is as follows:

```js
{
    "agg_fq": "2013 - FQ1",
    "quarterly_sum": 12748,
    "dys": 92,
    "avg_per_day": 138
}, {
    "agg_fq": "2013 - FQ2",
    "quarterly_sum": 12161,
    "dys": 90,
    "avg_per_day": 135
}, {
    "agg_fq": "2013 - FQ3",
    "quarterly_sum": 12410,
    "dys": 91,
    "avg_per_day": 136
}, {
    "agg_fq": "2013 - FQ4",
    "quarterly_sum": 12137,
    "dys": 92,
    "avg_per_day": 131
}, {
    "agg_fq": "2014 - FQ2",
    "quarterly_sum": 11970,
    "dys": 90,
    "avg_per_day": 133
}, {
    "agg_fq": "2014 - FQ3",
    "quarterly_sum": 9743,
    "dys": 91,
    "avg_per_day": 107
}, {
    "agg_fq": "2014 - FQ4",
    "quarterly_sum": 8294,
    "dys": 92,
    "avg_per_day": 90
}
```

The data charted for the line is the `dys` property.  The values are between `90` and `100` yet the chart label shows `0` - `1.0`.  I've tried looking into the `renderer` of the label and it shows the same issue and the values are incorrect.

Here is my chart as defined:

```js
{
    xtype: 'cartesian',
    store: store,
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    axes: [{
        type: "category",
        postion: "bottom",
        fields: "agg_fq",
        title: "Quarters",
        label: {
            rotate: {
                degrees: -45
            }
        }
    }, {
        type: "numeric",
        position: "right",
        grid: true,
        fields: ["avg_per_day"],
        title: "Emails"
    }, {
        type: "numeric",
        position: "left",
        title: "Days in Qtr",
        fields: ["dys"],
        renderer: function(value) {
            console.log(value);
        }
    }],
    series: [{
        type: "bar",
        axis: "right",
        xField: "agg_fq",
        yField: ["avg_per_day"],
        stacked: false
    }, {
        type: "line",
        axis: "left",
        xField: "agg_fq",
        yField: ["dys"]

    }]
}
```

Here is a [Sencha Fiddle with the issue](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ctv).

Answer (score 3):

After messing around with the code, I found the issue. The `yField` on a `line` series apparently causes issues if it is an array.  Changing the series to the following will fix the issue:

```js
{
    type: "line",
    axis: "left",
    xField: "agg_fq",
    yField: "dys"
}
```

And here is a [Sencha Fiddle with the fix](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/cue).